# Can't get armature to move mesh!

Tags: rendering, mesh, objects, rigging, bones

I am trying to get an armature to move one limb on a deer I have made. Here is my design process!

1. I made the body and limbs as separate meshes. I wasn't sure how to create limbs out of the body of the mesh and make them look good.
2. I tried joining  the meshes, creating the armature and setting automatic weights and then moving the armature in pose mode. The mesh would not move with the armature
3. I thought maybe it was because many vertices between the mesh and the limb were crossing so I thought maybe that was why the armature was not moving the limbs
4. I used the cut tool to remove the intersecting mesh on the limb and the body so that there were no intersecting vertices.
5. I then joined this set of meshes and created a new armature, set the weights to automatic and tried to move the mesh in pose mode and it still won't work.

What should I do? I don't know what else to try. I have been following any other online instructions exactly.

File Link: [image]

Comment: Could you please upload a .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or another similar site?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me and apologies for taking so long  to respond. I have uploaded the blend file. For different outcomes with the armature, I have the left side of the mesh with vertexes connected. The right side does not have vertexes connected. I cannot get the armature to connect to the mesh after applying automatic weights, thus I'm not seeing the point in weight painting until I do. I'm still new to blender. (file link): [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1316" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1316/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you needed to join all parts of the deer by selecting the misc ones, then the main one, and keying *Ctrl + J*.

You also needed to parent the mesh to the armature by first selecting the mesh, then the armature, and keying *Ctrl + P*. You would select *Armature Deform > With Automatic Weights*.

[image]

Lastly, some weight painting had to be done. I did all of this. Here is the finished .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried this process and it worked. Through my endless search of guides, I could not find the process stated exactly as you did. I am eternally grateful! :)

Comment: If this helped, consider accepting it.

Comment: Sorry how do I do that? Is it the checkmark? First time on stack in a while!

Answer (score -2):

Actually you must join all joints together with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
and then parent to the mesh, only then can you truly use the mesh with armature. One armature must become many, and use mesh with that just one! Awesome huh!

Joine all armatures! All becomes one, literally, just one armature with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

And then parent the mesh to that *one* armature that can use it, else you cannot do.

There cannot be multiple armatures on one mesh, because it must be parented under one armature and you cant use many... simply put unless you clone...

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any additional information compared to the currently accepted one.

Comment: he said all parts of the deer, he should of said all the armature and joints, then adding the "deer" mesh to it, also if in pieces, also join the mesh... this simply is clearer and i would of not found until i did what i needed to, heres the little guide...